# Cocos2dx :Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode5, cocos2d-x

I import a project cocos2dx into Xcode 5, then build it.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "cocos2d::extension::CocoLoader::ReadCocoBinBuff(char*)", referenced from:
      cocos2d::extension::CCDataReaderHelper::addDataFromBinaryCache(char const*, cocos2d::extension::_DataInfo*) in CCDataReaderHelper.o
      cocos2d::extension::CCComRender::serialize(void*) in CCComRender.o
      cocos2d::extension::GUIReader::widgetFromBinaryFile(char const*) in GUIReader.o
      cocos2d::extension::SceneReader::createNodeWithSceneFile(char const*, cocos2d::extension::AttachComponentType) in SceneReader.o
  "cocos2d::extension::CocoLoader::CocoLoader()", referenced from:
      cocos2d::extension::CCDataReaderHelper::addDataFromBinaryCache(char const*, cocos2d::extension::_DataInfo*) in CCDataReaderHelper.o
      cocos2d::extension::CCComRender::serialize(void*) in CCComRender.o
      cocos2d::extension::GUIReader::widgetFromBinaryFile(char const*) in GUIReader.o
      cocos2d::extension::SceneReader::createNodeWithSceneFile(char const*, cocos2d::extension::AttachComponentType) in SceneReader.o
  "cocos2d::extension::CocoLoader::~CocoLoader()", referenced from:
      cocos2d::extension::CCDataReaderHelper::addDataFromBinaryCache(char const*, cocos2d::extension::_DataInfo*) in CCDataReaderHelper.o
      cocos2d::extension::CCComRender::serialize(void*) in CCComRender.o
      cocos2d::extension::GUIReader::widgetFromBinaryFile(char const*) in GUIReader.o
      cocos2d::extension::SceneReader::createNodeWithSceneFile(char const*, cocos2d::extension::AttachComponentType) in SceneReader.o
  "cocos2d::extension::LabelReader::createInstance()", referenced from:
      cocos2d::extension::GUIReader::GUIReader() in GUIReader.o
  "cocos2d::extension::ButtonReader::createInstance()", referenced from:
      cocos2d::extension::GUIReader::GUIReader() in GUIReader.o
  "cocos2d::extension::LayoutReader::createInstance()", referenced from:
      cocos2d::extension::GUIReader::GUIReader() in GUIReader.o
  "cocos2d::extension::SliderReader::createInstance()", referenced from:
      cocos2d::extension::GUIReader::GUIReader() in GUIReader.o
  "cocos2d::extension::stExpCocoNode::GetChildNum()", referenced from:
```

I tried to remove i386 in Valid architechture, but it do not work
I don't know how to fix it. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that issue by going on the target properties of my project and in general tab there's a section called "Linked frameworks and libraries" I added here all the libraries my project uses and that's it, additionally I selected in section "Match-o type" in project properties linking section the option "Static library" also works with "Dynamic library".

Answer (score 1):

If your deployment target is 7 then change it to 6